# How can I flatten a list of Objects in nested Lists?

Tags: drools

I am working with drools in a rule and have a main fact that looks like this:

- Mainfact

  - ListOfTopObjects

    - TopObject

      - ListOfSecondLevelObjects

        - SecondLevelObjectA
        - SecondLevelObjectB
    - TopObject

      - ListOfSecondLevelObjects

        - SecondLevelObjectC

**What I want is a list that looks like this: [SecondLevelObjectA, SecondLevelObjectB, SecondLevelObjectC].**

I unsuccessfully tried following code:

```
$TopObjects: List()
    from collect( TopObject() from $MainFact.ListOfTopObjects)

$SecondLevelObjects: List()
    from accumulate( TopObject($x: ListOfSecondLevelObjects) from $TopObjects;
      collectList( $x ))
```

But this only produces a List that looks like this:
[[SecondLevelObjectA, SecondLevelObjectB], [SecondLevelObjectC]].

Is there a way to produce the flat list or to flatten the list produced in last step?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$MainFact( $topObjects: ListOfTopObjects )
$secondLevelObjects: List() from accumulate(
  TopObject( $subList: ListOfSecondLevelObjects ) from $topObjects,
  $x: SecondLevelObject() from $subList;
  collectList($x)
)
```

You need to `collectList` the individual items from the ListOfSecondLevelObjects, not the list itself.

Basically you need to add a second statement to the init clause of the `accumulate` to get each individual item out of the sub-list.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
I tried this and similar codes, but this always gives me an error message, that assigning a second time ($x: .....) is not possible.

For your suggested solution the error message is:
[KBase: defaultKieBase]: [ERR 102] Line 75:8 mismatched input ':' in rule "TestRuleNestedAccumulate"

Line 75 is "$x: SecondLevelObject() from $subList;"

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I only found a "hacky" way of solving it.

```
$secondLevelObjects: List() from
    from accumulate( TopObject($subList: ListOfSecondLevelObjects) from $TopObjects;
                    init(   List tmp_list= new ArrayList();),
                    action( tmp_list.addAll($subList);),
                              result( tmp_list ))
```

This uses java in the "action" section which does not seem very efficient. Maybe someone has a better idea?

Comment: Any reason you didn't just use [allAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) ?

Comment: No Reason. It is much cleaner and produces same result. Thanks :)
---- (changed original post, see change-log)

Comment: You could edit your question and add it and ask for a better idea.